# Wildlfy Remote Database Connection : java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I am getting the following issue when trying to connect remote database from the Wildfly server.

```
16-07-13 11:17:50,031 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'perpetulist.war#primary'
2016-07-13 11:17:50,270 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-07-13 11:22:25,587 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated the service container was 'add' at address '[
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]'
2016-07-13 11:22:25,672 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) PBOX00337: nextState for action getPolicyConfiguration: open
2016-07-13 11:22:25,673 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) PBOX00315: delete, contextID: perpetulist.war
2016-07-13 11:22:25,673 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) PBOX00337: nextState for action delete: deleted
2016-07-13 11:22:30,603 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@14294f63 for operation {"operation" => "add-deployer-chains","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:396)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1332)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1292)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1180)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.handleContainerStabilityFailure(AbstractOperationContext.java:964)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:590)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:354)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:330)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1183)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:453)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:384)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:359)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-07-13 11:22:30,605 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.server.DeployerChainAddHandler$FinalRuntimeStepHandler@14294f63 for operation {"operation" => "add-deployer-chains","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2016-07-13 11:22:35,608 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.SecurityRealmAddHandler$ServiceInstallStepHandler@1f6b87ac for operation {"address" => [("core-service" => "management"),("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")],"operation" => "add","map-groups-to-roles" => undefined} at address [
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:396)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1332)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1307)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1180)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.handleContainerStabilityFailure(AbstractOperationContext.java:964)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:590)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:354)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:330)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1183)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:453)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:384)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:359)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-07-13 11:22:35,610 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.SecurityRealmAddHandler$ServiceInstallStepHandler@1f6b87ac for operation {"address" => [("core-service" => "management"),("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")],"operation" => "add","map-groups-to-roles" => undefined} at address [
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("security-realm" => "ApplicationRealm")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2016-07-13 11:22:40,611 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.SecurityRealmAddHandler$ServiceInstallStepHandler@1f6b87ac for operation {"address" => [("core-service" => "management"),("security-realm" => "ManagementRealm")],"operation" => "add","map-groups-to-roles" => false} at address [
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("security-realm" => "ManagementRealm")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:396)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1332)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1307)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1180)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.handleContainerStabilityFailure(AbstractOperationContext.java:964)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:590)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:354)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:330)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1183)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:453)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:384)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:359)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-07-13 11:22:40,614 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.SecurityRealmAddHandler$ServiceInstallStepHandler@1f6b87ac for operation {"address" => [("core-service" => "management"),("security-realm" => "ManagementRealm")],"operation" => "add","map-groups-to-roles" => false} at address [
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("security-realm" => "ManagementRealm")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2016-07-13 11:22:45,616 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$ModelControllerServiceInitializationBootStepHandler$1@4cc494f for operation {"operation" => "boottime-controller-initializer-step","address" => []} at address [] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.waitForRemovals(OperationContextImpl.java:396)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.handleResult(AbstractOperationContext.java:1384)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:1332)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.finalizeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1307)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext$Step.access$300(AbstractOperationContext.java:1180)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.handleContainerStabilityFailure(AbstractOperationContext.java:964)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:590)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:354)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:330)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1183)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:453)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:384)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:359)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:271)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have verified that I can access the remote database server from my local machine and verified the connection through WildFly Management Console. This is the configuration I have for the remote datasource,

```
 <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/db_dev" pool-name="PostgresDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://IP_ADDRESS:5432/database</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>postgresql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
```

I am not sure what is causing this issue as I think that the datasource connection is fine and the same connection works for the localhost. I have enabled remote server access for postgresql as well.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration for remote datasource seems fine. There is a nice description about this [here](https://bgasparotto.com/enable-wildfly-remote-access/). By default, wildfly allows connections from localhost only. Therefore, to change this, we need to configure wildfly such that it is allowed to connect to remote sources as well.

Update the following section on standalone.xml,

```
<interface name="management">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
</interface>
<interface name="public">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
</interface>
```

With this:

```
<interface name="management">
    <any-address/>
</interface>
<interface name="public">
    <any-address/>
</interface>
```